# Prevent json_encode() from automatically generating integer keys

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to encode a two-dimensional PHP array to JSON with json_encode() and I'm having a problem:

My array looks like this:

```
$array = array( array( 1325368800, 6898 ) );
```

When I encode it to JSON using json_encode(), the output looks like this:

```
  'data' : [ 
          '0' : [  '0' : '1325368800',      '1' : '6898' ]
           ]
```

I would like to get rid of the automatically generated integer keys and have it like this:

```
'data':  [ [ '1325368800', '6898' ] ]
```

Any tips?

Comment: [It doesn't for me](http://codepad.org/LVWlwu5G).

Comment: What's wrong with `[ "0": [ "0: "123", "1": "123" ] ]`?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this is all the code you have and you don't get that output: `<?php
$array = array( array( 123, 123 ) );
echo json_encode($array); 
?>` ?

Comment: because Highcharts doesn't seem to like the generated integers (enough question marks?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only happen if you give the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag to `json_encode` ([live demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PWmwxe)):

```
echo json_encode(array(array( 123, 123 )));
// outputs [[123,123]]

echo json_encode(array(array( 123, 123 )), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
// outputs {"0":{"0":123,"1":123}}
```

Make sure the second argument of `json_encode` is not set, or set to a value generated by ORing `JSON_*` constants together.

If, however, the data is an associative array, you can use [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) to get a JSON array instead of a JSON object:

```
$assocData = array('0' => array('0' => 123, '1'=>123));
$arrayData = array_map('array_values', array_values($assocData));
echo json_encode($arrayData);
```

By the way, the JSON output you cited is invalid, since it uses square brackets (`[]`) for objects, and misses a quote after `"0`.

Comment: I have hard time believing you could get json_encode to literally output `[ "0": [ "0: "123", "1": "123" ] ]` no matter what. It is even missing a quote for crying out loud.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out Esailja, I was giving a simplified example. I modified the question to point out the problem with actual data.

Comment: @supertopi my point still stands even after your edit. Reproduce in http://codepad.viper-7.com

Comment: @supertopi It's always a good idea to give a reproducible example. The current version is better, but still not valid php. I updated this answer with a solution for a similar input.

Comment: Thanks phihag and Esaijlija for pointing out the encoding. With your answers I managed to trace the problems cause (which was in fact with the JavaScript JSON parser :)